# when soft keyboard is shown if dialog box is displayed there is a small jerk in the layout

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard

As i mention in title my problem is when soft keyboard is shown if dialog box is displayed there is a small jerk in layout it is very small but i don't want it.

Following is the code which i used.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to new page"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#24f40d"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/bt3"/></LinearLayout>
```

It is content main code.I just want that if we focus on edit text keyboard will displayed and if we press button dialog will display then there is small jerk in app.I don't want that.
If anyone know solution post it it will help a lot.Thanks in advance.

```
 public class button1layout extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button1layout);

        Button bt3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt3);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showChangeLangDialog();
                /*Intent i3=new Intent(button1layout.this,button3layout.class);
                startActivity(i3);*/
            }
        });

    }

    private void showChangeLangDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //do something with edt.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
}
```

This is main activity code